# Using employee(id, name, designation) object as key in hashmap, what method i need to overwrite

Tags: java

Say, i have two employee(id,name,designation) object e1(1,"ABC","SE"), e2(2,"DEF","SSE") and used as key like
hm.put(e1,"value1");
hm.put(e2,"value2"); // class of overridden with equals and hashcode method on the basis of id+name+designation

Let suppose i made a mistake like e2 object , i want "XYZ" as name.
What changes i needed to made in class so that e2 will have same value as "value2"

Condition : we cannot change hashcode equals overriden method .

Answer (score 1):

Mutable keys will broke the map state.  So the clean way would be to remove the element of the map, to change its state and to put it again in :

```
map.remove(e2);
e2.setName("XYZ");
map.put(e2, "...");
```

That will work but that is an error prone approach because the map state corruption may occur anywhere where the mutable employee is manipulated.
A robuster approach would be to make employee immutable to make explicit the `removing()` then `adding()` in the Map.

```
Employee e2 = new Employee.Builder().withId(...).withName(...).withDesignation(...).build();
e2.setXXX(...); // it will  not compile as no change state possible now
map.remove(e2);
e2 = e2.copy().withName("XYZ").build();
map.put(e2, "...");
```

Or with a arguments constructor (that is still ok for 3 parameters) and without providing setter of course:

```
Employee e2 = new Employee(id, name, designation);
e2.setXXX(...); // it will  not compile as no change state possible now
map.remove(e2);
e2 = new Employee(e2.getId(), "XYZ", e2.getDesignnation());
map.put(e2, "...");
```